# HLSL Primitive type size issue

Tags: types, size, hlsl

I was under the impression that the type float2x4 would occupy 32 bytes, however when I declare the following float2x4 varname[100], it occupies 64*100 bytes, not 32*100 bytes as expected. How come? Perhaps I'm not seeing something related to the padding of float2x4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

float2x4 is asking for 4 float2s. Since each "register" is 16 bytes wide (1 float4) then it uses 64 bytes worth of space to store the 4 float2s. Z and W in each of the 4 float4s is unused and acts as padding.

In contrast, float4x2 is asking for 2 float4s, and so fits perfectly into two float4 registers (32 bytes).

Comment: Ahh, it seems I mistook float2x4 for 2 float4's, my mistake, thank you for clearing it up.

Comment: Remember to accept the answer if this answers your question.

Comment: This is the opposite, the floatAxB is A rows of B columns.